# Many to Many relationship Subsonic 3 (SimpleRepository)

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Is this at all possible ? If it is possible could someone ilustrate a very simple example?

I can't create a many to many relationship.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the DB designer for this and carry out your model as you need to. There is no way to generate the relationships from migrations.

Comment: If there is no way to generate this, how do you bubble it up to the code level? I can only save either ObjectType1 or ObjectType2... how do I get and manage the relationship between these two objects in code in this senario. I want to load an instance of ObjectType1 and add a link between ObjectType1 and two other instance of ObjectType2. I could then load an Instance of ObjectType2 and do the same in reverse.

Would I need to manualy call SQL to manage this, or is there something in SimpleRepository I can use?

Comment: I can only imagin not having this functionality for the first 5 minutes of coding a new solution, then I would need to be able to do many-to-many realtionships.